# C: Freeing Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, free

I have this code:

```
node* free_tree(node *root){

  if(root != NULL){

    free_tree(root->left);
    free_tree(root->right);

    free(root->name);
    free(root);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

I know this isn't correct, correct version is with:

```
root -> left = free_tree(root->left);
root -> right = free_tree(root->right);
```

What I don't understand is, why does this work? When I return from  `free_tree(root->left)` with NULL, my function require that some 
`node*` receive NULL value, this is not the case here, so I don't get it, why does this work? Why is this not a compilation error?

Comment: Why would you expect to be required to assign a return value?

Comment: Why should it be a compilation error?

Comment: int funct(), in main I would have to do for example int x = funct(). Same here... Am I wrong?

Comment: You are just about to free the node in which you have assigned `NULL` values to left and right, so why bother to fill them in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple things:

1. There's no reason why this function needs to return anything.  The second version you show uses the return value to update the left and right pointers prior to freeing them, but (a) There's no need to since you're freeing the node anyway, and (b) The value is always `NULL`.  Since it's a constant, there's no reason to return it.
2. There's no compilation error because there are no type violations.  The only issue is that you're calling a function that returns a `node *` but aren't using the return value.  However, that's legal C.

Comment: So basically, 5; NULL; statements are correct? This answers my question, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: That's correct.  One type of statement in C is an "expression statement", which is just an expression followed by a semicolon.  The expression may have any data type, and its value is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

You are deleting the entire tree, and apart from the root pointer which should be set to NULL (or not even that, depending on the implementation), the members of nodes don't have to be set NULL.

Your correct code is identical to:

```
node* free_tree(node *root){

  if(root != NULL){

    free_tree(root->left);
    free_tree(root->right);

    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;

    free(root->name);
    free(root);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

As you can see right after the members `left` and `rigth` are set to NULL, the entire node is `free`d. So their values don't matter as far as the correctness of the program is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

The functions doesn't require assignment. The value is just thrown away if it is not needed.

```
int OutputSquareValue(int value) {
   int result = value * value;
   printf("%d", result);
   return result;
}
```

If you don't need the result in your code, but only want it to be outputed you go

```
OutputSquareValue(5);
```

And it is perfectly ok. If you need to use your new value, you go

```
printf("Squre of %d = ", x);
y = OutputSquareValue(x);
printf("%d^4 =", x);
OutputSquareValue(y);
```